# How can I place an ad below drawerlayout?

Tags: android

This is really hard to accomplish. My activity has this following XML. I want to place an ad above the bottom navigation, how can I accomplish this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="end">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:subtitleTextColor="@android:color/white"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_container">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:titleEnabled="false">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        app:tabGravity="fill"
                        app:tabMode="scrollable">
                    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

                </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_above="@+id/ad_view"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_filter_list_white_24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

        <!--<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView-->
            <!--xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/ad_view"-->
            <!--android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"-->
            <!--android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"-->
            <!--ads:adSize="BANNER"-->
            <!--ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>-->

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:elevation="12dp"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_main_nav_item_style"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_main_nav_item_style"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/platforms_filter_drawer"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryD"
        android:layout_width="215dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/filter_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="FILTER"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/header" />

            <Button
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/header"
                android:id="@+id/btn_clear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:text="CLEAR"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/md_red_600"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:background="@color/md_grey_600" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer_list"
            android:layout_width="215dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The AdView currently commented goes below the Bottom Navigation. I tried so hard to place it above the bottom navigation and under my fab button, but it doesn't seem to work, no matter what I try. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add LinearLayout around Bottom Navigation Bar and ad and set the orientation to vertical view as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="end">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:subtitleTextColor="@android:color/white"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_container">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:titleEnabled="false">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        app:tabGravity="fill"
                        app:tabMode="scrollable">
                    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

                </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_above="@+id/ad_view"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_filter_list_white_24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/ad_view"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:elevation="12dp"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_main_nav_item_style"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_main_nav_item_style"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/platforms_filter_drawer"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryD"
        android:layout_width="215dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/filter_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="FILTER"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/header" />

            <Button
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/header"
                android:id="@+id/btn_clear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:text="CLEAR"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/md_red_600"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:background="@color/md_grey_600" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer_list"
            android:layout_width="215dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is no adview in your answer, and linerlayout around bottom nav doesn't have opening tag? Is this normal? I'm new to android